# Triple integral in mathpazo

Tags: mathpazo, integral

Using

```
\iiint
```

seems to work fine to generator a triple integral. However, it doesn't seem to work if I include

```
\include{mathpazo}
```

in the preamble. Any solutions for this? I am using the Palatino font for the main text. The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amssymb}                    
\usepackage{amsthm}                 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}                         

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

This should be a triple integral:
\begin{align}
\iiint\limits_V \dif V \, (\nabla\phi)^2 = 0.
\label{eqn:triple_integral}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot, yes I actually have \usepackage{mathpazo}. I already have amsmath loaded.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example that produces the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `mathpazo` package, which provides Palatino-clone text and math fonts, hasn't been updated in a long time. As you've discovered, it also lacks macros to generate double- and triple-integral symbols.

An up-to-date alternative to `mathpazo` is the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` pair of packages. A side-benefit of loading `newpxmath` is that it provides a `\iiint` macro by default -- as well as several other, compatibly styled integral symbols.

Since `newpxmath` loads the `amsmath` package automatically (if it hasn't been loaded already), there's no need to load `amsmath` in separate instruction. Likewise, unless the `noamssymbols` option is set, the `newpxmath` package loads the pxfonts version of amssymb -- no need to load the `amssymb` package separately either

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
$\int \oint \iint \iiint \displaystyle\int \oint \iint \iiint$

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP provided a full MWE: The `newpxmath` and `newpxtext` packages must be loaded after `amsmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fouriernc} % not compatible with Palatino
\usepackage{amsmath}    % is loaded automatically by 'newpxmath' package
%\usepackage{amssymb}   % no need to load this package either
\usepackage{amsthm}                 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}                         

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\section{A Section}

This should be a triple integral:
\begin{equation} \label{eqn:triple_integral}
\iiint\limits_V \! \dif V \, (\nabla\phi)^2 = 0.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you provide works. However, if I adjust the MWE above to replace mathpazo  with the packages you suggest, I get an error in compilation: "Option clash for package amsmath".

Comment: That works great. Just a final question on this: Why is fouriernc not compatible with Palatino? I am not well versed with the font packages on LaTeX.

Comment: @Sid - I meant to write, "*visually* not compatible". Fourier is rather different from Palatino. I can see no reason for trying to mix-and-mismatch them.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `amssymb` should *not* be loaded if `newpxmath` is used, as the `newpxmath` package option `amssymbols` loads `pxfonts` version of the AMS symbols. This assumes, of course, that the user wants to use Palatino-compatible math font.

Comment: @RuixiZhang - Thanks! I've commented out the instruction in question.

Comment: `amsmath` is loaded by `newpxmath`. The `centertags` is default, so it is not necessary to use it.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using  `xelatex` or `lualatex` makes things easier:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}                 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}                         

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
    \section{A Section}
    This should be a triple integral:
    \begin{equation} \label{eqn:triple_integral}
    \iiint\limits_V \! \dif V \, (\nabla\phi)^2 = 0.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to be a tad more explicit what it is about LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX that "makes things easier".

Answer (score 4):

The error is in loading `fouriernc`, which is for using New Century Schoolbook, rather than Palatino. Load either it or `mathpazo`, not both.

The `centertags` option is active by default for `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

This should be a triple integral:
\begin{equation}
\iiint\limits_V (\nabla\phi)^2 \dif V = 0.
\label{eqn:triple_integral}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different option is to use `newpx` (`amsthm` should be loaded before it) and `amssymb` should be removed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

This should be a triple integral:
\begin{equation}
\iiint\limits_V (\nabla\phi)^2 \dif V = 0.
\label{eqn:triple_integral}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This compiles fine. However, I reduced the MWE too minimally. I must be loading another package that is conflicting with these updates since the integral signs are still missing. I have update my MWE to contain more information.

Comment: I had an \usepackage{fourier} sneaking in the preamble too. This I believe was the conflict since the integral signs do appear now.

Comment: Omitting `\usepackage{amsthm}` leads to the appearance of erroneous 'plain plain plain definition plain plain' string of words at the beginning to the thesis. I can only assume it plays some additional role to that covered by `newpxmath`

Comment: @Sid You can omit `amsmath`, not `amsthm`, as shown in my code. Of course, `fourier` should be removed, too, as its effect is similar to that of `fouriernc`.

Answer (score 2):

A good. modern replacement for `mathpple`/`mathpazo`/`pxfonts`/`newpxmath` is Asana Math, which was originally based on Young Ryu’s `pxfonts`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures={Common, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
% If you’re using mathrsfs, you probably want to use \mathscr, but you also
% load amssymb.  The following line sets up a \mathcal and \mathbfcal similar
% to the ones from ammsymb, in addition to \mathscr and \mathbfscr similar to
% rsfs.
\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, Alternate]{Asana Math}

% URW Classico is a free clone of Optima, which matches the free clones of
% Palatino well.
%\setsansfont{URWClassico}[
%   UprightFont = *-Regular ,
%   BoldFont = *-Bold ,
%   ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
%   BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
%   Extension = .ttf ]

%\setmonofont{Inconsolata} % A humanist monospaced font.

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\mathrm{d}} 

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

This should be a triple integral:
\begin{align}
\iiint\limits_V \dif V \, (\nabla\phi)^2 = 0.
\label{eqn:triple_integral}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Asana Math Sample]

For comparison, `mathpazo` with a double integral:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.

\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\mathrm{d}} 

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

This should be a triple integral:
\begin{align}
\iint\limits_V \dif V \, (\nabla\phi)^2 = 0.
\label{eqn:triple_integral}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: mathpazo example]

My recommendation is to use `unicode-math` whenever you can, and legacy font packages when you have to.  Any modern math font has more symbols with more consistency and more flexibility than any combination of legacy packages.  If you’re stuck with PDFTeX, I suggest replacing `\usepackage{mathpazo}` with `\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}`.